# How to perform the reverse of `xargs`?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a list of numbers that I want to reverse.

They are already sorted.

`35 53 102 342`

I want this:

`342 102 53 35`

So I thought of this:

`echo $NUMBERS | ??? | tac | xargs`

What's the ???

It should turn a space separated list into a line separated list.

I'd like to avoid having to set `IFS`.

Maybe I can use bash arrays, but I was hoping there's a command whose purpose in life is to do the opposite of xargs (maybe xargs is more than a one trick pony as well!!)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `printf` for that. For example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 35 53 102 342
35
53
102
342
$ printf "%s\n" 35 53 102 342|tac
342
102
53
35
```

Comment: Wow. that is what I call a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Would be better to use %s, so that it won't break if the number contains a decimal point or is too large.

Comment: @mark4o: hadn't thought about that at all, thanks for the tip.

Comment: ... or has a leading 0 and an invalid octal digit. To pick a completely arbitrary example that I've never run into.

Answer (score 13):

Another answer (easy to remember but not as fast as the printf method):

```
$ xargs -n 1 echo
```

e.g.

```
$ NUMBERS="35 53 102 342"
$ echo $NUMBERS | xargs -n 1 echo | tac | xargs
342 102 53 35
```

Here is the `xargs` manual for `-n` option:

```
-n number
         Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for 
         each invocation of utility.  An invocation of utility will use less 
         than number standard input arguments if the number of bytes accumu-
         lated (see the -s option) exceeds the specified size or there are 
         fewer than number arguments remaining for the last invocation of 
         utility.  The current default value for number is 5000.
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed when i looked for the reverse of xargs, thanks. Since `echo` is the standard command used by xargs, you could even omit it like `echo $NUMBERS | xargs -n1 | tac | xargs`

Answer (score 8):

awk one-liner without tac:

```
awk '{NF++;while(NF-->1)print $NF}'
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "35 53 102 342"|awk '{NF++;while(NF-->1)print $NF}'
342
102
53
35
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use [Bash string manipulation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/)

```
$ numbers="35 53 102 342"
$ echo "${numbers// /$'\n'}"
35
53
102
342
$ echo "${numbers// /$'\n'}" | tac
342
102
53
35
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could write:

```
echo $(printf '%s\n' $NUMBERS | tac)
```

where `printf '%s\n' ...` prints each of `...`, with a newline after each one, and `$( ... )` is a built-in feature that makes `xargs` almost superfluous.

However, I don't think you should avoid using arrays, `IFS`, and so on; they make scripts more robust in the face of bugs and/or unexpected input.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of answers using `tac`, but in case you'd like to use sort, it's almost the same:

```
printf "%s\n" 1 2 3 4 5 10 12 | sort -rn
```

`n` is important as it makes it sort numerically. `r` is reverse.

Answer (score 2):

If you have sorted your list with `sort`, you might considered the `-r` reversed option

Answer (score 1):

Another way to change space into newlines and the other way round is with `tr` :

```
echo 35 53 102 342|tr ' ' '\n'|tac|tr '\n' ' '
```

If data is not sorted, replace `tac` by `sort -rn`.